# Pin headers too long for the sensor i bought

Tags: adafruit

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adafruit-TCS34725-Color-Sensor-Filter/dp/B00OKCRU5M/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=adafruit+rgb+sensor&qid=1559653098&s=computers&sr=1-3

Just bought this colour sensor for a project and as you can see it comes with the pins detached. There are 8 pins but only 7 holes so how do i assemble it? I'm assuming its super obvious since i havent seen anyone else ask it so im sorry!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cut one pin off.

Get some wire cutters and position them in the groove between the last and next to last pins in the row. Squeeze. One pin will pop off.

Comment: Ok, will do. Why did they make it like that though? It's not just mine, you can see in the picture that all of them are like that

Comment: @ThisUsernameHasBeenTaken Simple: you can't (easily and cheaply) buy 7-pin headers, but you can buy 8-pin. They could cut them down to 7 pins for you, but that would cost more.

Comment: Didn't matter i screwed up the soldering so i need to buy a new one...